# No user_loader Exception at random times (disappears on reset)

Tags: flask, flask-login

I run flask in debug mode and quite often, when I make changes and reload a page, I get thrown a `No user_loader` exception

> Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Refer tohttps://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works for more info.

I have a `user_loader` written right after I define my `User` class (it's moved around):

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

This error persists on every refresh of the page *until I reset the flask app itself* despite being in debug mode. Then the error disappears.

Is this a known bug or something to be expected?

## UPDATE

So it's been a while since I posted this question but it just got an upvote so someone is experiencing a similar problem. I've gotten more experience with this problem so I might be able to elucidate the problem a bit:

After a major refactor of my app I started getting a similar sort of exception (can't remember the exact exception) essentially saying that a given module can't be found (I believe it was a route). It seems to occur most often when I make certain changes to the SQLA models or some other kind of extensive change.

I wish I could be more clear but the error is mysterious and it often appears when I least expect it. There is certainly a kind of change that can be made to the code that results in the debug-mode server failing and needing to be restarted.

I know that is still not very illuminating, but it's certainly more accurate than the first half of this post.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, it is quite unfortunate but it remains as mysterious a bug as I've ever had to deal with. Very flaky.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. I was also getting this error:

```
Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Refer to https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works for more info.
```

Here was my declaration of the user_loader function:

```
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

It turns out, as I was copying pasting from the tutorial, I pasted the load_user function **AFTER**:

```
return app
```

In other words, the execution of the code never reached my user_loader declaration. Make sure your return statement is after your user_loader declaration.